# Remove C++ class names from binary dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, obfuscation

I have a C++ project under Visual Studio 2010 which compiles into a dll. I have several private implementation-specific classes defined in my project, e.g. `CMyClass`. This class is not exported from the dll or by any interface function. However, when I check generated dll file, there is a string "CMyClass" stored in it. It is a release build, and I don't want this string to appear in the dll file. This dll is shipped to customers, and I want all names I used in my project to be stripped off the dll file, so nobody can get such a simple clue on what algorithms we use in our dll.

I use Release configuration. In project properties, the "Generate Debug Info" option under linker tab is turned off, the "Debug Information Format" under C/C++ tab is set to "Program Database (/Zi)". I tried to set empty string for "Debug Information Format" with no success.

The string found in the dll looks like `.?AVCMyClass@@` and is located at the very end of the dll file. It is the only occurrence of the "CMyClass" string in the dll file. However, this string is presented for almost all my internal classes.

How to get rid of these mentions?

**Update**

Please note, I don't want to *obfuscate* the source code itself. The provided link is irrelevant. I just see no reason why class names are stored in the dll file. I can always rename my classes prior to build, but it is not very straight solution.

**Update2**

I don't agree with community on closing this qustion, since this is not a duplicate. And the answer is given in comments by [Tyler Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960081/tyler-gill). Thanks to him and shame on others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code

Comment: "I don't want this string to appear in the dll file" What is the exact reason why you think the name of the class to be hidden. Compiling a C++ code is enough obfuscation in itself!

Comment: @Ram Because the names of classes correspond to the names of the algorithms we use to solve the problem. We don't want anyone to know what algorithms do we use.

Comment: @Ram Concerning the link: thanks, but that's not what I really want. I don't need to obfuscate the code, I want to remove the names from the binary file. And I hope, Visual Studio linker itself can do this somehow.

Comment: Dude - what you compile is what you get :).  It sounds like you probably want to get an [obfuscator](http://www.stunnix.com/prod/cxxo/overview.shtml), and release the obfuscated version of your .dll's and .exe's.

Comment: @paulsm4 I see no reason why class names should appear in the dll, and I want to remove them. It is not about obfuscation, it's about linkage. I can always rename class names myself before linkage, but I believe it is not necessary.

Comment: Is RTTI enabled in for the files you're compiling? It creates objects that store information about the types and adds them to the binary, and one of the properties it has is the name of the type.
Other than that, it seems like obfuscation is the way you want to go. If the compiler's putting the class names into the binary, then it's doing it for a reason. But you should be able to use an obfuscation tool to rename your internal classes for you.

Comment: @TylerGill Yes, `CMyClass` actually inherits `IMyClass`. However, I don't use any `dynamic_cast`s in my project. Do you want to say than once I use inheritance with polymorphism there will be names of polymorphic classes stored in binaries?

Comment: @Mikhail - I think it is a waste of time performing obfuscation. Even if you give your classes weird names a decompiler would still give a person the algorithm. If they are prepared to work that out and give the variables reasonable names, then it is a small jump to give the class a reasonable name. So you have to rely on a license, protect that license and also the fact that it is cheaper to buy the binary from you than decompile it.

Comment: @TylerGill Your guess is actually an answer. If I disable RTTI with /GR- switch, the names are no longer presented in the dll file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0(v=vs.100).aspx If you want, you may post an answer and I will upvote+accept it :)

Comment: @Mikhail: Hope you are not using stuff that neetds RTTI like dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As my guess from a comment appears correct, I'm reposting this as an answer.

The string of the class name is a result of having RTTI (Runtime Type Information) enabled for the compiled binaries. When RTTI is enabled, the compiler creates objects that store information about the types compiled into the binary, one of whose properties is the name of the type.

Note that some uses of `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` require RTTI, so disabling will cost you those features of C++.

In order to disable RTTI in Visual Studio, use the `/GR-` switch (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as Mikhail posted.)

To disable it in GCC, use the `-fno-rtti` switch.

Comment: Did the same and it worked only for part of the class names. For others the RTTI wasn't enough. Apparently when using "std::bind" with virtual functions - the class name may appear in the binary even if RTTI is disabled. Simply don't use std::bind (or related function)

Answer (score 2):

As [Tyler Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960081/tyler-gill) mentioned in the comments, this string was left by compiler due to RTTI since `CMyClass` actually inherits `IMyClass` and is polymorphic. My problem can be easily solved by [disabling RTTI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we6hfdy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `/GR-` switch. Thanks.